# How to access Server side exception object in JS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I have a situation where i need to throw UserDefined Exception(setting Some message) from server side controller and need to show same message in the UI(angularJS $http call)

here is some sample code snippets

```
//In Server

@RequestMapping(value = "get-tax", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String,Object> getEligibleTaxes()throws GrnException{
        throw new GrnException("Catch Me if you can.....in UI");
    }

//In UI

var taxesResponse = GRNCommonService.getEligibleTaxes();
    taxesResponse.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //console.log("Taxes :"+angular.toJson(data));
        if(data.status){
            GRNMasterInfo.setEligibleTaxes(data.responseData);
        }else{
            alert("Failed to Get Taxes Information!...Because :"+data.message);
        }
    });
    taxesResponse.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Data :"+data);
        console.log("Status :"+status);
        console.log("Header :"+headers);
        console.log("Config :"+angular.toJson(config));
        alert("Failed to Get Taxes Information!");
    });
```

Comment: In js controller ,add success and failure method in service call. So that after failure at server side  failure method will be called. and get response at failure method like this    function error(response) {}. This response will show exception message. I m not sure ,but i think it will work

Comment: thnx for response...here i can get that response in error block but...i want to get user defined exception object (which i thrown at server side) as a java script object...but i'm getting the exception message as embeded in html content whit rootcause and stackstrac...etc

Comment: can you post the exception message that you are getting at client side and also the user defined exception java class strucutre.